# Density of smooth functions in the calculus of variations

Tags: reference-request, geometric-measure-theory, calculus-of-variations

In the non-convex calculus of variations, in the context of non-linear elasticity, the following classes of mappings $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, were introduced by John Ball [B]:
$$
A_{p,q}=\{u:\, \nabla u\in L^p,\ \ \operatorname{adj}\nabla u\in L^q\},
\quad
p>\frac{n}{n-1},\ q\geq\frac{p}{p-1}.
$$
$$
A_{p,q}^+=\{u\in A_{p,q}:\, \operatorname{det}\nabla u>0\ a.e.\}.
$$
This class of mappings was investigated by Šverák [S] and you can find more information by searching papers on MathSciNet that cite papers by Ball and Sverak.

> **Question.** What is known about density of smooth functions in $A_{p,q}$ and $A_{p,q}^+$ spaces?

I am interested both in density in the weak and strong topology, but mostly in the strong topology.

**[B] J. M. Ball,**
Convexity conditions and existence theorems in nonlinear elasticity.
*Arch. Rational Mech. Anal.* 63 (1976/77), no. 4, 337–403.

**[S] V. Šverák,**
Regularity properties of deformations with finite energy.
*Arch. Rational Mech. Anal.* 100 (1988), 105–127.

Comment: I guess, if you care to decipher their notation, then I guess Giaquinta, Modica & Soucek "Cartesian currents in the calculus of variations" should have the state of the art when the book was written (see in particular Section I.3.4, but possibly also elsewhere). On the other hand, the book was written more than 20 years ago, so possibly there has been some newer development, so I won't post this as an answer. I believe though that in particular for $A^+_{p,q}$ the problem should still mostly be open.